# AngularJS ng-model using Controller As and Typescript to Populate selection

Tags: angularjs, typescript, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-options

I am new to coding. I am working on some code that uses Angular,Typescript, and Controller As instead of scope and can't find any examples that are not using $scope.something.

I currently have a popover menu with several options. When one option is selected it opens a slider that shows the empty select input box. I want the slider to open with the selection from the popover menu assigned to the input box.

Currently in my HTML I have:

```html
<select name="entryTypes" ng-model="vm.entry.type">
    <option value="option1">Option One</option>
    <option value="option2">Option Two</option>
    <option value="option3">Option 3</option>
</select>
```

I want to place my options inside my controller instead. I think ng-options is how to accomplish this but I am at a loss.

Comment: create an array with the options in your controller and then go through it in your html using ng-options. It is quite easy and there are hundreds of examples out there. Just change `scope` by the name you set in `controllerAs`

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ng-options` directive,
in your `controller` :

```
$scope.items = [{
  id: 1,
  label: 'Option One',
  subItem: { name: 'aSubItem' }
}, {
  id: 2,
  label: 'Option Two',
  subItem: { name: 'bSubItem' }
}];
```

And HTML :

```
<select ng-options="item as item.label for item in items track by item.id" ng-model="selected"></select>
```